# What is the limit of this function as $n$ tends to infinity?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, limits

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring it out.
My first step is always to convert $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ to  $\sin(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ and then I get stuck here. Because I'm not quite sure where  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n}(-\sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ leads....:/

Please help.

EDIT

My Thomas' Calculus text book (12th Edition) lists the identity as being $$cos(A-\frac{\pi}{2}) = sin(A)$$ so naturally (or perhaps, naively?) I went ahead and took my A to be $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: If you know that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$ - see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1) - the rest should be easy. Also $\cos(\pi/2-x)=\sin x$; are you sure about your conversion?

Comment: Have you tried graphing this function on a calculator? That should at least help you guess what the answer should be.

Comment: The title is sweetly absurd.

Comment: @did *embarrassed*

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, I'll use an app I have on google chrome and see where the graph leads me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\cos(\frac\pi2-x)=\sin x$

$\cos(\frac\pi2-\frac 1{\sqrt n})=\sin \frac 1{\sqrt n}$

Put $h=\frac 1{\sqrt n},$ so, $h\to 0$ as $n\to ∞$

So, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$

$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n}\sin(\frac 1{\sqrt{n}})$

$=\lim_{ h\to 0}\frac{\sin h}{h}=1$

Comment: @Siyanda, welcome; hope I could clear the idea.

Answer (score 2):

## Hint

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n}\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}.$
What did you know about $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow  0}\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}$?

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped. :)